# Spark, unable to connect to master using submit script

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to submit application to spark using the submit script. I have 3 nodes, 1 master & 2 workers. I have configured /etc/hosts:

> 127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain localhost
>
> 10.90.110.173 spark1
>
> 10.90.110.177 spark2
>
> 10.90.110.179 spark3

I also added these to my conf/spark-env.sh:

> export  SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1
>
> export  SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.127

And this is what my submit script looks like:

> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" \
>
> --master spark://spark1:7077 \
>
> $(find target -iname "*.jar")

I get an error message that it cannot connect to my master.

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/10/08 20:03:03 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/10/08 20:03:03 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/10/08 20:03:03 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/10/08 20:03:03 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/10/08 20:03:03 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 35920.
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@127.0.0.127:36246]
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 36246.
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-0ed2efc4-9df9-4099-9a4b-efa69e8b40f3
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://127.0.0.127:4040
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-04551a15-1f26-4dc9-9a5e-ff637a6ac1bc/httpd-ebc736d7-339e-4253-ba71-5be690d2fb65
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 46354.
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/local/spark/simpleapp/target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar at http://127.0.0.127:46354/jars/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar with timestamp 1475974984849
16/10/08 20:03:04 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark1:7077...
16/10/08 20:03:05 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark1:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
16/10/08 20:03:24 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark1:7077...
16/10/08 20:03:24 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark1:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
16/10/08 20:03:44 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark1:7077...
16/10/08 20:03:44 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark1:7077...
16/10/08 20:03:44 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark1:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
16/10/08 20:04:04 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark1:7077...
16/10/08 20:04:04 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark1:7077...
16/10/08 20:04:04 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
16/10/08 20:04:04 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
16/10/08 20:04:04 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark1:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: spark1/10.90.110.173:7077
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
16/10/08 20:04:04 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 43668.
16/10/08 20:04:04 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 43668
16/10/08 20:04:04 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/10/08 20:04:04 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 127.0.0.127:43668 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 127.0.0.127, 43668)
16/10/08 20:04:04 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://127.0.0.127:4040
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/10/08 20:04:05 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
16/10/08 20:04:05 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1039)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient.stop(AppClient.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$cluster$SparkDeploySchedulerBackend$$stop(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.stop(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1582)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$9.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1740)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1739)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.dead(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.markDead(AppClient.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AppClient.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(AppClient.scala:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-04551a15-1f26-4dc9-9a5e-ff637a6ac1bc/userFiles-6d5eb5da-4b3a-4ecd-a5e2-c1799fcc5abb
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-04551a15-1f26-4dc9-9a5e-ff637a6ac1bc/httpd-ebc736d7-339e-4253-ba71-5be690d2fb65
16/10/08 20:04:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-04551a15-1f26-4dc9-9a5e-ff637a6ac1bc
```

Is there a list of things that I can check when I run into this kind of problem? I searched many other articles but none seem to work for my problem.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Spark master ip and local ips must be resolvable from other nodes so you must be using the actual ipv4 address(10.series in your case) instead loopback address.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify.. Should I have three lines instead?
export  SPARK_MASTER_IP=10.90.110.173
export  SPARK_LOCAL_IP=10.90.110.177
export  SPARK_LOCAL_IP=10.90.110.179

Comment: I actually solved this by changing my submit script: $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" \

--master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 \

$(find target -iname "*.jar")